# How to run connect Display to GUI app running in docker container when docker service is running on remote server

Tags: docker, user-interface, vnc, xserver

What can we do if my docker service is running on a remote server with no display, and we need to connect the GUI app running in the docker container to the DISPLAY at the local system?

In my scenario I have a remote server running docker so can we forward the display to the local machine in this scenario?

```
Local Linux system [where the display is required]
<->
remote server [ssh access available, docker installed, no display]
<->
Docker container[running GUI app]
```

Is it possible with Xorg or in this case VNC needs to be used?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest the following:

1. install xrdp on the container to enable remote desktop there
2. open firewall port 3389 for incoming tracfic of the container.
3. use "docker run -p :...." to map some port (maybe 3389) of the remote host to the container's port 3389 so that when you remote desktop to your remote host, the system will redirect the traffic to the right container's port.
4. From your PC, for example a Windows 10 machine, open Remote Desktop Connection client and connect to your remote host with port 3389.
5. Launch your app on the container using the RDC GUI.